# Как создать такой календарь на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, calendar

Как создать такой календарь? (Проект на React.js)

[image: Custom Calendar in JavaScript]

Comment: CLNDR - https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR
Demo - http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/

Comment: Какой отвратительный календарь Даже советовать не хочется, чтобы такое не создали  Ну вообще библиотек много, даже обычный поиск `react calendar` выдаёт 100500 ответов. Всё очень сильно зависит от требуемой функциональности. Если надо просто показать, то это самая обычная таблица. Если не очень сложный функционал то и самому можно написать реактивность. Если уже что-то очень сложное, то надо искать либу, благо их не мало на реакте. А ещё можете взять либы типа `moment.js` чтобы чисто с дататми работать, но рисовать самому

Comment: @EzioMercer  Вообще-то это начало годового плана. По этой календаря создается задачи. 100% согласен с вами. Очень неприятный((. Наверное на изучение этого у сотрудников уходит месяц.

Comment: Начал использовать библиотеку https://year-calendar.github.io/js-year-calendar/docs/index.html